# I can't assign an ID to an already loaded Java script

Tags: javascript

I tried everything and couldn't link my Image IDs to a preloaded Generic.js file in the Head section. Here's my HTML below:

```
<div id="bgimgwrapper">
  <noscript>
    <div>
      <img id='bgNoScript' src='index_files/background1.jpg'
           alt='' title='' width='100%' height='100%' />
    </div>
  </noscript>
  <img class="active" id="bg0" src="index_files/background1.jpg"
       style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <img id="bg1" src="index_files/background2.jpg"
       style="width: 100%; display: block;">
</div>
```

`bg0` and `bg1` should be assigned to a function inside the preloaded generic.js, here's the function:

```
function bgStart() {
  setCurrentCycle();
  $bg = $('<img style="width:100%">'), bg = $bg[0];
  $bg.hide().load(bgLoad);
  $bg.addClass("active");
  bg.id = "bg" + currentCycle;
  bg.src = slideArray[currentCycle];
  $bg.appendTo("#bgimgwrapper");
  theWindow.resize(resizeBg)
}
```

`bgStart()` basically is a background image slider. In firebug though, I can't even see the evaluation "ev" sign next to each ID divs. Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't understand why you are using 2 references for your new bg element... how about:

```
  $bg = $('<img style="width:100%">');
  $bg.hide().load(bgLoad)
     .addClass("active")
     .attr('id', 'bg' + currentCycle)
     .attr('src', slideArray[currentCycle])
     .appendTo("#bgimgwrapper");

  theWindow.resize(resizeBg);
```

Comment: dear ymz, the bgstart() function as is already a predefined function in the generic.js library. i'm just calling it so i can fire up my slider. The problem is that the link between the ID and the Library isn't taking place for some reason.